# Execution failed for task: 'compileJava' android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I am new to java, and I successfully printed hello world before, but things happened and I had to reset my computer. Now I have android studio and java downloaded again, and suddenly the same exact code cannot be compiled.

```
package com.example;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println{"HELLO WORLD");
    }
}
```

The below are from the Messages panel

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:lib01:assemble]
Information:11/9/2017 8:02 PM - Compilation completed with 6 errors and 1  
warning in 29s 437ms
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':lib01:compileJava'.
 > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
C:\Users\chong\Desktop\Java\Android_Studio\Week1\lib01\src\main\java\>com\example\MyClass.java

Error:(4, 18) Gradle: error: not a statement
Error:(4, 26) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(4, 27) Gradle: error: not a statement
Error:(4, 40) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(6, 1) Gradle: error: reached end of file while parsing
```

I don't understand the errors, because it is asking me to insert ; in the middle of the code. plz help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After println you have a bracket not a parenthesis.

You have println{"Hello World);.

When it should be println("Hello World");.

Comment: LOL thank you!!!! What a silly error. I fixed the syntax and it compiles now hahaha. I should get a rubber duck for myself

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks to be written for a console application. I'm sure somebody will correct me, but I don't think android studio has the ability to be used for creating console applications.

If you are just starting out, jumping right into the deep end of android app development could be painful to say the least.

As an alternative, I would suggest getting the latest version of [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/ide/)! Create a new console application and try the code you posted again.